# Inbound path processor is not processing

Tags: routes, 9

I'm trying to use an Inbound Path Processor to redirect a path([to a webapp based on this tutorial](https://redfinsolutions.com/blog/embedding-react-app-drupal-8-site)), but Drupal is not picking it up.

I tried the following code to simply redirect every page on the site to `/happy`, but after rebuilding the cache, nothing happens; I can navigate the site normally and never get redirected.

**/mymodule/src/PathProcessor/MyPathProcessor.php**

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\PathProcessor;

use Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\InboundPathProcessorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MyPathProcessor implements InboundPathProcessorInterface {

  public function processInbound($path, Request $request) {
    return '/happy';
  }

}
```

Am I using this wrong?  What do I need to do to get Drupal to use the path processor?

Comment: This is not a redirect by the way. Path processing is like rewriting in .htaccess without `[R,L]`. If you want to rewrite the path with a redirect you can use an event subscriber. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2013014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A path processor is a service tagged with *path_processor_inbound*. For example, this is the definition of the *path_processor.files* path processor used by Drupal core.

```yaml
path_processor.files:
  class: Drupal\system\PathProcessor\PathProcessorFiles
  tags:
    - { name: path_processor_inbound, priority: 200 }
```

Keep in mind that all the path processors are invoked. If the path set by a path processor isn't used from Drupal, another path processor could have changed it. Services like *path_processor.files* use the priority for that reason: to avoid conflicts with other services of the same type which, in this case, could change the path already altered by another path processor.